# Does postfix virtual domain accept wildcards?

Tags: postfix, email

Can I set up a virtual domain on one box so that a few specific email addresses get forwarded to gmail, and everything else (using a wildcard) goes to another system I control?    For example, can I put in /etc/postfix/virtual

```
me@xcski.com me@gmail.com
my_wife@xcski.com m_wife@gmail.com
*@xcski.com *@home.xcski.com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this for a wildcard:

```
@xcski.com @home.xcski.com
```

(ie. what you had without the asterisks). From the `VIRTUAL(5)` documentation:

```
# RESULT ADDRESS REWRITING
#        The lookup result is subject to address rewriting:
#        
#        o      When  the  result  has  the  form @otherdomain, the
#               result becomes the same user in otherdomain.   This
#               works only for the first address in a multi-address
#               lookup result.
```

Comment: The problem with the catch-all approach is that it'll unfortunately also forward all the emails that are sent to random usernames at that specific domain. IME 99% of those emails are spam...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but wildcard rewriting defeats address validation. The usual disclaimers about catchall addresses apply in that case.

The usual advice, if you have a list of known/valid addresses, is to let the computer do the work for you and generate /etc/postfix/virtual from your database of known addresses (or use a database maptype). Make(1) is your friend.